# Weird popup each time ubuntu 12.04 boots up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, wubi

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04, there **was** an interruption in the download, however the s/m seems to be working fine, just that each time I boot up I get the following message

`Failure to download extra data filesName-ar.UTF-8: فشل تنزيل ملفات البيانات الإضافيةName-ast.UTF-8: Fallu al descargar ficheros de datos estraName-bn.UTF-8: অতিরিক্ত ডাটা ফাইল ডাউনলোড করতে ব্যর্থ হয়েছেName-bs.UTF-8: Neuspjelo učitavanje dodatnih datoteka  s podacimaName-ca.UTF-8: Ha fallat la baixada dels fitxers de dades addicionalsName-da.UTF-8: Kunne ikke hente ekstra datafilerName-de.UTF-8: Herunterladen von zusätzlichen Datendateien schlug fehlName-el.UTF-8: Αποτυχία λήψης επιπλέον αρχείων δεδομένωνName-en_AU.UTF-8: Failure to download extra data filesName-en_GB.UTF-8: Failure to download extra data filesName-eo.UTF-8: Fiasko dum elŝutado de pliaj datumdosierojName-es.UTF-8: Fallo al descargar archivos de datos extraName-fi.UTF-8: Ylimääräisten tiedostojen lataus epäonnistuiName-fr.UTF-8: Échec du téléchargement des données supplémentairesName-gd.UTF-8: Dh'fhàillig luchdadh a-nuas faidhlichean dàta a bharrachdName-gl.UTF-8: Fallo na descarga de ficheiros extra de datosName-he.UTF-8: הורדת קובצי נתוני נוספים נכשלהName-hr.UTF-8: Greška pri preuzimanju dodatnih podatkovnih datotekaName-hu.UTF-8: Nem sikerült letölteni az extra adatfájlokatName-id.UTF-8: Gagal mengunduh berkas data ekstraName-it.UTF-8: Scaricamento file dati extra non riuscitoName-ja.UTF-8: 追加データのダウンロードに失敗Name-km.UTF-8: បាន​បរាជ័យ​ក្នុង​ការ​ទាញយក​ឯកសារ​ទិន្នន័យ​បន្ថែមName-lt.UTF-8: Nepavyko atsiųsti papildomų duomenų failųName-lv.UTF-8: Neizdevās lejupielādēt papildus datu failusName-ms.UTF-8: Gagal memuat turun fail data tambahanName-nl.UTF-8: Downloaden van extra gegevensbestanden is misluktName-oc.UTF-8: Fracàs del telecargament de las donadas suplementàriasName-pt_BR.UTF-8: Falha ao baixar arquivos de dados adicionaisName-ro.UTF-8: Eșec la descărcarea fișierelor cu date suplimentareName-ru.UTF-8: Ошибка загрузки дополнительных файлов данныхName-sk.UTF-8: Zlyhalo stiahnutie ďalších dátových súborovName-sl.UTF-8: Napaka med prejemom dodatnih podatkovnih datotekName-sq.UTF-8: Dështoi shkarkimi i skedarëve të të dhënave ekstraName-sv.UTF-8: Misslyckades med att hämta extra datafilerName-tr.UTF-8: Fazladan veri dosyalarını indirme başarısızName-ug.UTF-8: قوشۇمچە سانلىق-مەلۇمات ھۆججەتلىرىنى چۈشۈرۈش مەغلۇپ بولدىName-uk.UTF-8: Не вдалось завантажити додаткові файли данихName-vi.UTF-8: Lỗi khi tải các tập tin dữ liệu bổ sung xuốngName-zh_CN.UTF-8: 下载额外数据文件失败Name-zh_TW.UTF-8: 下載額外資料檔案失敗

The following packages requested additional data downloads after package installation, but the data could not be downloaded or could not be processed.

ttf-mscorefonts-installer

The download will be attempted again later, or you can try the download again now.  Running this command requires an active Internet connection.`

And asks me to run the installer, and then asks for password. However the popup just disappears only to re-appear when I reboot .Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem before. I think how I fixed it was just to reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer. From a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```