# update information message box

Tags: 12.04, updates, flash, info

I recently updated to 12.04. Each time I login, I get an update information message box written in many languages:

> Failure to download extra data filesName-ar.UTF-8: فشل تنزيل ملفات البيانات >الإضافيةName-ast.UTF-8: Fallu al descargar ficheros de datos estraName-bn.UTF-8: অতিরিক্ত >ডাটা ফাইল ডাউনলোড করতে ব্যর্থ হয়েছেName-bs.UTF-8: Neuspjelo učitavanje dodatnih datoteka  s >podacimaName-ca.UTF-8: Ha fallat la baixada dels fitxers de dades addicionalsName->da.UTF-8: Kunne ikke hente ekstra datafilerName-de.UTF-8: Herunterladen von >zusätzlichen Datendateien schlug fehlName-el.UTF-8: Αποτυχία λήψης επιπλέον αρχείων >δεδομένωνName-en_AU.UTF-8: Failure to download extra data filesName-en_GB.UTF-8: ?>Failure to download extra data filesName-eo.UTF-8: Fiasko dum elŝutado de pliaj datumdosierojName-es.UTF-8: Fallo al descargar archivos de datos extraName-fi.UTF-8: Ylimääräisten tiedostojen lataus epäonnistuiName-fr.UTF-8: Échec du téléchargement des données supplémentairesName-gd.UTF-8: Dh'fhàillig luchdadh a-nuas faidhlichean dàta a bharrachdName-gl.UTF-8: Fallo na descarga de ficheiros extra de datosName-he.UTF-8: הורדת קובצי נתוני נוספים נכשלהName-hr.UTF-8: Greška pri preuzimanju dodatnih podatkovnih datotekaName-hu.UTF-8: Nem sikerült letölteni az extra adatfájlokatName-id.UTF-8: Gagal mengunduh berkas data ekstraName-it.UTF-8: Scaricamento file dati extra non riuscitoName-ja.UTF-8: 追加データのダウンロードに失敗Name-km.UTF-8: បាន​បរាជ័យ​ក្នុង​ការ​ទាញយក​ឯកសារ​ទិន្នន័យ​បន្ថែមName-lt.UTF-8: Nepavyko atsiųsti papildomų duomenų failųName-lv.UTF-8: Neizdevās lejupielādēt papildus datu failusName-ms.UTF-8: Gagal memuat turun fail data tambahanName-nl.UTF-8: Downloaden van extra gegevensbestanden is misluktName-oc.UTF-8: Fracàs del telecargament de las donadas suplementàriasName-pt_BR.UTF-8: Falha ao baixar arquivos de dados adicionaisName-ro.UTF-8: Eșec la descărcarea fișierelor cu date suplimentareName-ru.UTF-8: Ошибка загрузки дополнительных файлов данныхName-sk.UTF-8: Zlyhalo stiahnutie ďalších dátových súborovName-sl.UTF-8: Napaka med prejemom dodatnih podatkovnih datotekName-sq.UTF-8: Dështoi shkarkimi i skedarëve të të dhënave ekstraName-sv.UTF-8: Misslyckades med att hämta extra datafilerName-tr.UTF-8: Fazladan veri dosyalarını indirme başarısızName-ug.UTF-8: قوشۇمچە سانلىق-مەلۇمات ھۆججەتلىرىنى چۈشۈرۈش مەغلۇپ بولدىName-uk.UTF-8: Не вдалось завантажити додаткові файли данихName-vi.UTF-8: Lỗi khi tải các tập tin dữ liệu bổ sung xuốngName-zh_CN.UTF-8: 下载额外数据文件失败Name-zh_TW.UTF-8: 下載額外資料檔案失敗
>
> The following packages requested additional data downloads after package installation, but the data could not be downloaded or could not be processed.
>
> flashplugin-installer
>
> The download will be attempted again later, or you can try the download again now.  Running this command requires an active Internet connection.

I reinstalled the flashplugin-installer, but still got this message box. I have even deleted it completely but still the message appears after login.

How to fix it?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/134992/weird-popup-each-time-ubuntu-12-04-boots-up)

Comment: @beeju no it is not.. the other question has a problem for some fonts this is a problem with flash

Comment: @Ashu.Yes u r right.Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably a bug and is reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/987965)

**Another solution you have is***  -
Type the following two commands

> cat /var/lib/update-notifier/user.d/data-downloads-failed
>   cat /var/lib/update-notifier/user.d/data-downloads-failed-permanently

If any one of htem gives you the same error which you are getting then type
`sudo rm /var/lib/update-notifier/user.d/data-downloads-failed`

---

*i would suggest you not to use the commands & wait till the bug gets fixed.